# expo does not contain an export named WebBrowser

Tags: react-native, expo

I have the basic example of using Expo.WebBrowser and it gives the error:

`import { WebBrowser } from 'expo'`

`'expo' does not contain an export named 'WebBrowser'`

Dependencies:

`"buffer": "^5.1.0",
    "color-hash": "^1.0.3",
    "debug": "^3.1.0",
    "eventemitter2": "^5.0.1",
    "expo": "^27.0.2",
    "mobx": "^4.3.0",
    "mobx-react": "^5.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "mqtt": "^2.18.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-app-rewire-mobx": "^1.0.8",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.52.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "^3.10.0",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-storage": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-swipeout": "^2.3.3",
    "react-native-web": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-web-webview": "^0.2.5",
    "react-router-native": "^4.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.0",
    "svgs": "^3.1.2"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like in a browser environment WebBrowser is not available.

Using 'react-native-web' causes `import { WebBrowser } from 'expo'` to fail.